# Proof verification of theorem regarding $m$-tail of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

> Prove that  a sequence $X=(x_n)$ converges iff its $m$-tail $X_m$($m\in \mathbb N$) converges. For that case, $lim X=lim X_m$.

**Proof**:If $X$ converges to $x$, then for a given $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ $K\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq K$, $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$. $\forall k \in \mathbb N$ with $k \geq K-m$
we have $|x_k-x|<\varepsilon$ for $x_k$ being a term in $X_m$ . Thus, if we take $K_m$(the choice of natural number for sequence $X_m$) as the least among $k$ then we can conclude that $X_m$ converges to $x$.
If $X_m$ converges to $x$ then for a given $\varepsilon>0$ ,$\exists K \in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq K$ ,$|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ for terms of $X_m$. For all $h\in 
\mathbb N$ with $h \geq K+m$ , $|x_h-x|<\varepsilon$ for terms of $X$. we can choose the required natural number for $X$ as $K+m$ so as to get that $X$ converges to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proof:

Let $\ X=(x_n)\ $ be a real sequence, let $\ X_m\ (m\in\mathbb{N})\ $ be an m-tail of $\ X,\ $ that is, $\ X_m=(x_n)_{n\geq m}.\ $ Then,

$$X_m\ \text{converges}$$

$$ \iff\ \text{given} \ \varepsilon>0,\ \exists\ M\geq m\geq 1\ \text{such that}\ \vert x-x_n\vert<\varepsilon\quad \forall\ n\geq M\ $$

$$ \iff X=(x_n)_{n\geq1}\ \text{converges.}$$

I'm not sure more detail is necessary unless you want to be ultra-rigorous?